# CSS alignment of div tags that form boxes around letters

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a pattern of showing three letters or words in boxes of equal sizes, and the boxes are connected and different colors.  I finally got that accomplished with a these style items "display:inline;float:left;".  But now when I try to put text before or after it, or put two of these sets of boxes on the same screen, things go crazy.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/cmjmb/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    font - size: 300 % ;
}
div.boxtype1 {
    background - color: #2BFFE3;display:inline;float:left;
}
div.boxtype2
{
background-color:# 00806F;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
Before
<div class='test boxtype1'>A</div>
<div class='test boxtype1'>B</div>
<div class='test boxtype2'>C</div>
After
<br /><br />

Before
<div class='test boxtype1'>A</div>
<div class='test boxtype1'>B</div>
<div class='test boxtype2'>C</div>
After
<br /><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `float:left` automatically makes an element `display:block` so I think the `display:inline` is redundant. From your question it sounds like a fundamental misunderstanding of how `float` works.

Comment: True, I read the docs, and I still don't get what some of the parms mean.  Works fine now without display:inline.  Changing from display:inline to display:inline-block changes the size of the boxes, not sure I understand why that happens.

Comment: `display:inline` makes the element behave like a word in a paragraph. You can't give it size or affect its position - it will come straight after the previous element/text. `display:inline-block` is similar except that the element can now have a width and a height. How the elements/text before and after it align with it vertically is influenced by the css property `vertical-align`.

Comment: Ahhh - I was wondering why my width wasn't working (in my real-world scenario).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `float: left` you take the boxes out of the normal flow of elements, they 'float' to the left and the normal text floats around them. Probably that's not, what you wanted.

If you just leave out `float: left` it looks more like what you described. Still there is some space between the boxes. This is the normal white space, that is inserted between two words. You can avoid that by writing the three divs on one line - with no space in between.

Answer (score 3):

Put those text nodes inside a tag, like `<p>` for example. The you can just use `display: inline-block` for `div` and `p`:

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/cmjmb/4/

Comment: Boxes much touch, look like one "control", that's why I had the display:inline;float:left;  This is what I'm getting now: http://jsfiddle.net/fXz78/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
br { clear: both;}
```