# HTML CSS for Vertical Boxes with Text

Tags: html, css

Is it even possible to do something like this with just text, HTML and CSS? 
The image is a screen shot from my old Windows program that I'm rebuilding for the web and mobile platforms.

[image]

In this post, several people helped me do a series of horizontal boxes: 
[CSS alignment of div tags that form boxes around letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525529/css-alignment-of-div-tags-that-form-boxes-around-letters)

Here's the goal.  I'm creating a WordPress shortcode, which generates HTML.  I'd like to do something like this in WordPress:

```
[showvowel vowel=KAMATZ letter=ALEF] 
[showvowel vowel=PATACH letter=ALEF] 
[showvowel vowel=SEGOL letter=ALEF]
```

and then later I might do the same thing with totally different letters (some pages might have just one or two, other might have three to five.

```
[showvowel vowel=KAMATZ letter=GIMMEL] 
[showvowel vowel=PATACH letter=GIMMEL]
```

I've already got the information to build the text in a JSON structure.

The idea is to create a re-useable subroutine that would dynamically build the HTML to create whatever letter and vowel I want to show at any given time.  So once I figure out how the presentation works in browser, then no problem for me to put it into WordPress shortcode.

If you have an idea for a sample, no need to show the Hebrew letters, I've got that mastered.

HTML5 flexbox looks really cool, but not ready for primetime yet. 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

If I have to, I guess I could flip it sideways and make it horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use tables, then I would use div boxes with css. It is simple, and works on the majority of web browsers.

See: http://linuxandfriends.com/2009/04/04/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/

HTML:

```
<div class="div-table">
<div class="div-table-caption">Top Portion</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
<div class="div-table-col">Next Down</div>
</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
<div class="div-table-col">Next Down</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div-table{display:table; border:1px solid #003399;}

.div-table-caption{display:table-caption; background:#009999;}

.div-table-row{display:table-row;}

.div-table-col{display:table-cell; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #003399;}
```

EDIT:

Note: to have three columns you will need to use a wrapper.

Comment: Here's your example: http://jsfiddle.net/NealWalters/Mj8A9/ The problem is that the second box goes down the page, not to the right. I'm not opposed to tables either: http://jsfiddle.net/NealWalters/Mj8A9/#fork, but same issue. 
I think I could get it to work for one page, but I'm striving to wrap it in a ShortCode that can be re-used.  So each set of three boxes must be independent of the structure around it. 
I guess I could code a "wrapper-table" in the WordPress page, and each cell of that could contain a short code to the specific letter/vowel that I'm trying to show.

Comment: Also, I'm using a responsive layout (skeleton theme) which allows content to easily refloat for mobile devices.

Comment: You could just add float:left; margin-left:5px; to each table element.

Comment: I'm not following what that does; I gave it a try here.  http://jsfiddle.net/NealWalters/Mj8A9/1/

Comment: by floating an element left, you can add multiple items and have them align to the left of each other, say for 3 you would have left, center, and right and for 6 you would 2 rows of the same - automatically.